# Power electronics problem: battery charger

Tags: power-electronics, converter

Given the next circuit, I have to charge the battery of 12V with the one of 48V with a power transfer of 480W.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmVtzn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since inductors don't consume power on steady-state and switches are considered ideal, the average current \$i\$ taken by \$V_2\$ has to be \$40 A\$. Also, the average voltage drop across the inductor must be \$0\$ in steady-state so, let \$D\$ be the duty cycle and \$T\$ be the period of commutation:

$$
(V_1-V_2)DT = V_2(1-D)T \quad \Rightarrow \quad D=0.25 \quad (25\%)
$$

Now, how can I get the average \$40 A\$ to get the \$480W\$ on \$V_2\$?

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment. Show your efforts and attempts so far.

Comment: Two things. Even an ideal voltage source will not consume current unless the input voltage is greater than the voltage source set point. This means that the current will be less than 40A to get 480W of power transfer, slightly with an ideal source but still less. Second, this is a buck converter, google it...